# Count the number of items in an element[0]

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to calculate how many teams are in one element.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avinashjairam/avinashjairam.github.io/master/question2_data%20.csv', header=None)

for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    
    team_info = rows.to_list()
    
    team_id = team_info[0]
    
    wins = team_info[1]
    
    losses = team_info[2]
    
    ties = team_info[3]
    
    print(team_id, wins, losses, ties)
    print(f'Team {team_id} has {wins} wins, {losses} losses, and {ties} ties.')
    
    total_games_played = wins + losses + ties
    
    print(f'Total Games Played: {total_games_played}')
    
    games_remaining = 16 - total_games_played
    
    if games_remaining == 0:
        print('The season is finished.')
    else:
        pass
    
    print(f'Total Games Remaining: {games_remaining}')
    
    winning_average = (wins/total_games_played) if total_games_played != 0 else 0
    
    print(f'The Winning Average is: {winning_average:.4f}')
    
    if (ties >= wins):
        print('The number of tied games are greater than or equal to the number of wins.')
    else:
        print('The number of tied games are not greater than or equal to the number of wins.')
    
    
    if ties >= losses:
        print('The number of tied games are greater than the number of losses.')
    else: 
        print('The number of tied games are not greater than the number of losses.')
        
    
    wip_total = (wins + ties) - (3 * losses) 
    
    
    if wip_total < 0:
        print(f'The Wip Total is: 0.')
    else:
        print(f'The Wip Total is: {wip_total}')

Total_Number_of_Teams = len(int(team_id))
print(f'The Total Number of Teams are {Total_Number_of_Teams}.')
```

But, I receive this error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-f8b0a4f5d307> in <module>
----> 1 Total_Number_of_Teams = len(int(team_id))
      2 print(f'The Total Number of Teams are {Total_Number_of_Teams}.')

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I tried to use the len() function and the count function() to solve this part, but I receive the same error message. How would I go about counting the number of teams in the team_id?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are receiving this error is because the len() function expects an object, not an "int".

My suggestion is that when you fill the list you convert it to int:

```
team_id = int(team_info[0])
```

Just Note that your team_id needs to be only int numbers, otherwise the conversion will fail.

Then to count the length of this you only use:

```
Total_Number_of_Teams = len(team_id)
```